# How to properly use button toggle function

Tags: javascript, html

`button1Toggle()` function doesn't seem to work.  Text in the button doesn't change. Can't find the bug.

```js
 function button1Toggle() {
    if (document.myform.button1.value == "Mute") {
         document.myform.button1.value = "Unmute";
      } else {
         document.myform.button1.value = "Mute";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>Tablet</div><br>
<form name ="myform">
    <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Mute" onclick="button1Toggle()">
</form>
```

Comment: write: document.getElementById('button1').value

Comment: you code seems fine.. probably your code have another bug

Comment: Your code is works, or maybe some `browser` issues?

Comment: Maybe you have another button with the same id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have another button with the same id?

Try -

```
function button1Toggle(btn) {
    if (btn.value == "Mute") {
        btn.value = "Unmute";
    } else {
        btn.value = "Mute";
    }
}


 <div>Tablet</div><br>
     <form name ="myform">
        <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="Mute" onclick="button1Toggle(this)">
    </form>
```

Comment: or more concisely: `button1Toggle(btn) { btn.value = (btn.value === "mute")? "unmute" : "mute"; }`